# Cannot call function with different number of (3, 4, or 5) arguments

Tags: c#, arrays

The goal of this logic program is to return true if the first number or last number in the numbers array is 6 else return false. My logic is all fine and dandy but i can't figure out why it won't compile.
the error i am getting

> Error 1   No overload for method 'FirstLast6' takes 3 arguments
>   Error   2   No overload for method 'FirstLast6' takes 4 arguments
>   Error   3   No overload for method 'FirstLast6' takes 5 arguments

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    FirstLast6(1, 2, 6);        // -> true
    FirstLast6(6, 1, 2, 3);     // -> true
    FirstLast6(13, 6, 1, 2, 3); // -> false
}

public static bool FirstLast6(int[] numbers)
{
    if (numbers[0] == 6 || numbers[numbers.Length - 1] == 6)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing the parameter correctly to that method. Call it with an array arg, like this:

```
FirstLast6(new int[] { 1, 2, 6 });
```

Same thing applies for the other two calls.

Comment: @user3121357: No problem. You might want to at least look into the other answers as well, since the variable arguments list can be cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) keyword:

```
public static bool FirstLast6(params int[] numbers)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) to accept any number of arguments of the same type as an array.

```
public static bool FirstLast6(params int[] numbers)
{
```

This way, you will not need to create an array manually (Ex: `FirstLast6(new int[] { 1, 2, 6 });`), if you are trying to pass x amount of numbers to your method,